# Download Logs from Loki

Tags: azure, kubernetes, grafana, grafana-loki

I have a grafana Loki logs that's in my cluster. I am able to see my logs but as at the moment, the cluster is no longer in use and I would like to delete it but I still have some logs I would like to extract Loki and maybe store it locally on my system, or Azure bucket.

Is there a way to extract this logs and save locally or azure bucket. I used loki helm to setup my Loki, promethus any help is appreciated

Answer (score 13):

You could use `logcli` to connect to Loki. See this [documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/getting-started/logcli/).

Example command:

```
port-forward <my-loki-pod> 3100
logcli query '{ job="foo"}'  --limit=5000 --since=48h -o raw > mylog.txt
```

Answer (score -2):

Grafana Loki limits the number of log lines it can return in a single query response. By default this limit is [set to 5000](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/v2.8.x/tools/logcli/#batched-queries). This limit applies both to the [HTTP query API](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/api/#query-loki) and to [logcli](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/getting-started/logcli/). This limit may prevent from exporting all the logs from Grafana Loki if it contains billions of log lines :(

You can use [an alternative database for logs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/VictoriaLogs/) I work on, which allows querying all the logs in a streaming manner with a simple `*` query according to [these docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/VictoriaLogs/querying/#command-line).

Comment: Nice try)
The limit you mentioned in Loki could be easily increased.